# Deploying my customized Ubuntu to other machines

Tags: custom-distributions, custom-installer

Recently I customized Ubuntu 13.04 with our company theme,color, logos and icons and programs that the company needs mainly for the developers.

My question is simple and I hope the answer is simple as well or even if it's complicated it doesn't matter.

Is there a way I can make a redistributable ISO so that it can be installed into another computer?

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did it once following [LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch). It's clean and elegant, but it's not so easy.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is perfect for your problem. Just download the program, burn it to a disk, and use it to back up your installation to an iso file, then burn that file to a disk.

Comment: I wonder if it's still working 4 years after (newer versions of Ubuntu etc)